# How to extract values from pdf in .net c#

Tags: c#

How to extract values from pdf in .net c# and store it in a readable format in .net like text file, html
actually i need a pdf parser.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a PDF parser, use one.

There are many around - a good free one is [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Answer (score 1):

Aspose has a good PDF parser, if you'd rather buy a parser, but I've been waiting a long time for some bugs to be fixed.